# How to type Axios.all when the each promise has a different return type

Tags: typescript, axios, typescript-typings

I have two Axios `get` requests, for which the return types have been explicitly declared. Here's a simplified example:

```
interface O1 {
   prop1: string;
   prop2: boolean;
}

interface O2 {
   prop3: number;
   prop4: string;
}

interface Request<T> {
   message: string;
   data: T
}
```

Using these interfaces, I've typed my requests and the result object is also typed:

```
const getO1 = () => Axios.get<Request<O1>>("/API/O1");
const getO2 = () => Axios.get<Request<O2>>("/API/O2");
```

Now I need to make this calls in parallel, so I've tried `Axiox.all` but TypeScript complains the the `O1` and `O2` types do not match. Specifically, I've tried:

```
const getAll = () => Axios.all([getO1(), getO2()]);
```

From what I can see, TypeScript expects that, in the case of `all`, all results will have the same type (structure). Is there a way of having a typed concurrent call? (using Axios v0.18 and TypeScript v3.0.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the declaration for `Axios.all` is not very good. The way it is typed you can't pass in a tuple.

```
export interface AxiosStatic extends AxiosInstance {
  all<T>(values: (T | Promise<T>)[]): Promise<T[]>;
}
```

The parameter has to be an array of a single type `T`. Typescript will not infer a union for `T` and can't infer a tuple where an array is expected.

We can have a look at how `Promise.all` is typed (which does support tuples)

```
all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike <T4>, T5 | PromiseLike<T5>, T6 | PromiseLike<T6>, T7 | PromiseLike<T7>, T8 | PromiseLike<T8>, T9 | PromiseLike<T9>, T10 | PromiseLike<T10>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10]>;
// ...
all<T1, T2, T3, T4>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike <T4>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4]>;
all<T1, T2, T3>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3]>;
all<T1, T2>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>]): Promise<[T1, T2]>;
all<T>(values: (T | PromiseLike<T>)[]): Promise<T[]>;
```

We can see that they use a lot of overloads to support tuples.

If Axios promises are spec compliant, you could use try using `Promise.all`. The types work out, but I have not tested the runtime behavior myself.

```
const getAll = () => Promise.all([getO1(), getO2()]) //() => Promise<[AxiosResponse<Request<O1>>, AxiosResponse<Request<O2>>]>
```

Or you can stick with the axios version and use some type assertions:

```
const getAll = () => Axios.all<{}>([getO1(), getO2()]) as unknown as AxiosPromise<[Request<O1>, Request<O2>]>
```

Just a fun note, in 3.1 we will be able to type `all` without the 10 overloads:

```
type PromiseResult<T> = T extends AxiosPromise<infer R>? R: T
type ArrayPromiseResult<T extends (any | AxiosPromise<any>)[]> = { [P in keyof T]: PromiseResult<T[P]> }
declare function all<T extends [] | (any | AxiosPromise<any>)[]>(values: T): AxiosPromise<ArrayPromiseResult<T>>

let result = all([getO1(),getO2()]) // result is AxiosPromise<[Request<O1>, Request<O2>]>
```

Comment: Using `Promise.all` works, but then I have the overhead of getting the data from response (which Axios does automatically). I'd probably need to handle errors as well. It requires further research... Still, it's a valid solution. Using the type assertion `as unknown as AxiosPromise<[Request<O1>, Request<O2>]>` could also be considered. Although I don't really like casting (I could have gone with casting directly in the response), this solution would have the casting in the same place as the function, so it would have a better chance of being spotted when changing the promises inside `all`.

Comment: Please note that axios.all is deprecated in 2022. Read this https://blog.logrocket.com/using-axios-all-make-concurrent-requests/ and read this https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1042

Answer (score 0):

You can create an base interface and let your O1 and O2 interfaceses extending this interface. Use the base interface as the generic type paramter inside the Axios.all statement.

```
  import Axios from 'axios';

    //base interface
    interface axiosResponse{}

    //extend the base interface in both interfaces
    interface O1 extends axiosResponse {
        prop1: string;
        prop2: boolean;
    }

    interface O2 extends axiosResponse {
        prop3: number;
        prop4: string;
    }

    interface Request<T> {
        message: string;
        data: T
    }

    const getO1 = () => Axios.get<Request<O1>>("/API/O1");
    const getO2 = () => Axios.get<Request<O2>>("/API/O2");

    //specify the base interface type as the generic type parameter
    const getAll = () => Axios.all<axiosResponse>([getO1(), getO2()]).then( r => {
      const result: O1 = <O1>r[0];
      const result2: O2 = <O2>r[1];
    })
```

Comment: The results are not correctly typed. In `then` you'll get an array of `axiosResponse` but what I need is an array where the fist element is of type `O1` and the second of type `O2`.

Comment: You can cast the result into the desired subtype (Anwser edit).

Comment: That's not really fun. Sure, I can cast the result, but what happens when I have many more requests and their order changes? TypeScript will not be able to tell that I'm accessing a different object (type). Although casting works, it doesn't really scale and it adds the overhead of manually making changes in multiple locations.

Comment: True. The result looks not realy scaleable. At the moment i have no different approach - sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your help!